# d3.js creating two elements per data point

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm wanting to add another `rect` element behind each bar, but I'm struggling to do this because d3.js isn't allowing me to add another element for each data point.

http://jsfiddle.net/g5hpwf0m/2/

```
var w = parseInt(d3.select(self).style("width")),
    h = parseInt(d3.select(self).style("height")),

    svg = d3.select(self)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h),

    yScale = d3.scale.linear()
             .domain([0, d3.max(dataset)])
             .range([0,h]);

svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("fill", "green")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - yScale(d);
        })
        .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
        .attr("height", function(d){return yScale(d);});
```

I've tried adding this, but it doesn't do anything.

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - yScale(d);
        })
        .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
        .attr("height", "100%");
```

Comment: you need to add 2 rects in same level?

Comment: Like in the image on the fiddle, I want 1 rect to act as the background grey box of the bar, and then another rect that represents tha actual data point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to create a 'g' element and place the rects under each respective 'g' element.

```
var toprects = svg.append('g').attr('class','toprect');
var bottomrects = svg.append('g').attr('class','bottomrect');

bottomrects.selectAll("rect")....
toprects.selectAll("rect")....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ermineia/g5hpwf0m/3/